# What is X11rdp?

Tags: vnc, rdp, xrdp, x11rdp

I have been using xrdp for sometime now (along with vnc4server) and I think I understand high-level overview of its working as described [here](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/documents/asession/index.html). xrdp allows to communicate with RDP protocol and uses sesman for user authentication. After authentication a new/existing VNC session is used for remote display.

However, there is no description of X11rdp in the above process. I do see an option with name sesman-X11rdp on the login screen, which never works. I tried to look for the explanation of X11rdp on xrdp.org. All I could find is this: "Xrdp uses Xvnc or X11rdp to manage the X-session".

Can someone explain what is X11rdp and how it is different from Xvnc? What are the pros/cons of using X11rdp over xrdp-VNC?

PS: I could find a lot of tutorials on how to install/compile X11rdp. But, I first want to understand its purpose before going through the process of compiling/installing.

Answer (score 6):

X11rdp tries to improve on Xvnc by forwarding X11 draw commands as RDP draw commands instead of simply wrapping a vnc bitmap stream in RDP.

Draw commands are more bandwidth efficient as it can be vector based instead of just a raw video feed.  X11rdp vs Xvnc for the desktop is similar to MIDI vs WAV for music.  MIDI describes which notes are played while WAV simply encodes the resulting sound.

Comment: Dead link. Not enough info. in the description.

Comment: Removed dead link and added info to description.